# How long do Wrinklers need to suck before popping?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I'm currently at 5 Halloween cookies, and 552 Wrinklers popped. On a different machine, I am seeing similar poor performance. According to the [below chart](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/File:WrinlerChart.png), the odds of having this happen are negligable of me having so few Halloween cookies/ Wrinkler popped. I have traditionally been popping the wrinklers as soon as I see the CPS turn red, but I'm wondering if I'm just popping them too soon. Is there a certain amount of time that they need to suck, or am I just plain unlucky?

[image]

Comment: Just popped my 625th one, and I managed to get all of the cookies at last. Funny how that works sometimes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're popping them correctly.

The odds are *low*, which isn't quite the same as negligible. You are just the "lucky" demonstration of why each curve has a long flat tail all the way out into the 1000s on the x axis of that graph.

Answer (score 0):

Wrinklers help a lot but don't at the same time. They minus the CpS but they collect cookies too. When I leave this running overnight and while I'm at school when I come back a have over 11,000,000,000,000 which isn't a lot at my stage so I pop the wrinklers and I have 500,000,000,000,000